# Not printing in Colors

Tags: drivers, 16.04, printing

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 I have a strange problem with printing.
My documents are only printed in Black & White though I have a color printer. If I try from windows or other system (different Ubuntu version) it prints normally in color. I am new to Ubuntu, any fix for this please?

Details:

- Network Printer (Samsung CLP-620 series)
- Ubuntu 16.04.1
- PC: HP-Pavillion-500 series

Thanks a lot